# Promise in sequence does not stop when a promise reject

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a list of promises.

```
var p1 = {
    run: function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve("Promise 1 done");
            }, 2000);
        })
    }
};

var p2 = {
    run: function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                reject("Promise 2 reject");
            }, 1000);
        })
    }
};

var p3 = {
    run: function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve("Promise 3 done");
            }, 1500);
        })
    }
};
```

I want to execute `[p1,p2,p3]` in sequence. I writed a function `Process.sequence` to act like `Promise.all()` (resolve when all promises resolve, and reject right after a promise rejects)

```
Process = {
    sequence: function(promises){
        window.promises = promises;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            promises.reduce(function (sequence, promise) {
                return sequence.then(function () {
                    return promise.run();
                }).then(function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    if (promises.indexOf(promise) == promises.length - 1) {
                        resolve("All Done");
                    }
                }).catch(function (reason) {
                    reject(reason);
                });
            }, Promise.resolve());
        });
    }
};
```

But when i run `Process.sequence`...

```
Process.sequence([p1,p2,p3]).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
}, function(reason){
    console.log(reason);
});
```

... the `p3` still executed even `p2` had rejected before.

Here is the result i expect:

```
Promise 1 done
Promise 2 reject
```

But this is the real result:

```
Promise 1 done
Promise 2 reject
Promise 3 done
```

What wrong with my function `Process.sequence`?

**UPDATE**

Thank @JaromandaX for your support. The function `Process.sequence` should be like this.

```
Process = {
    sequence: function(promises) {
        return promises.reduce(function(sequence, promise) {
            return sequence.then(function() {
                return promise.run();
            }).then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
        }, Promise.resolve()).then(function() {
            return "All Done";
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: FYI you never get the "All Done" because you have a return statement right before your if statement, anything after that is never run

Comment: avoid the Promise constructor anti-pattern

Comment: @PatrickEvans , Thank you, i fixed and it worked. But the main problem is still there

Comment: @JaromandaX can you explain more detail? How is the Promise constructor anti-pattern?

Comment: "I fixed and it worked" if it worked how come the main problem is still there ? what worked ?

Comment: due to how you've written promises.reduce, that will return a promise ... no need to wrap the promise returned by promises.reduce in a `new Promise`

Comment: @JaromandaX the `promises` is an array of objects.

Comment: your code is essentially https://jsfiddle.net/f3swpxyu/

Comment: @KhánhLê - yes, so? promises.reduce will return a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you a lot.

Comment: try a simple `return sequence.then(() => promise.run());` and get rid of the outside `Promise` constructor call

Comment: "*`window.promises = promises;`*"  - whaaat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want the results to contain all of the fulfilled values, and the promises only to be created ("run") when all previous ones were fulfilled, you should make some changes:

- Make your loop asynchronous, as you can only know whether to continue with the next promise or not when the previous one has resolved.
- Stop looping when a promise rejects
- Concatenate the results in an array as you progress

Furthermore, I would not call a variable "promise" when it is not a promise object... that will only bring confusion. Call it `task` or something. The promise here is what the `task.run()` method returns.

Here is how I would suggest to do it:

```js
// The p1, p2, p3 objects have been written more concisely using a helper function:
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const p1 = { run: _ => wait(2000).then(_ => "Promise 1 fulfilled") };
const p2 = { run: _ => wait(1000).then(_ => { throw "Promise 2 rejected" }) };
const p3 = { run: _ => wait(1500).then(_ => "Promise 3 fulfilled") };

const Process = {
    sequence: function (tasks) {
        return (function loop(results) {
            return results.length >= tasks.length 
                // All promises were fulfilled: return the results via a promise
                ? Promise.resolve(results) 
                // Create the next promise
                : tasks[results.length].run()
                    // When it fulfills, collect the result, and chain the next promise
                    .then(value => loop(results.concat(value)))
                    // When it rejects, return a rejected promise with 
                    // the partial results and the reason of rejection
                    .catch(reason => { throw results.concat(reason) });
        })([]); // Start with an empty results array 
    }
};

console.log('Wait for the results to come in...');
Process.sequence([p1, p2, p3]).then(function(result){
    console.log('Fulfilled: ', result);
}).catch(function(reason){
    console.log('Rejected: ', reason);
});
```

As browsers have started to support `async/await` you could also use this more procedural looking code:

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const p1 = { run: _ => wait(2000).then(_ => "Promise 1 fulfilled") };
const p2 = { run: _ => wait(1000).then(_ => { throw "Promise 2 rejected" }) };
const p3 = { run: _ => wait(1500).then(_ => "Promise 3 fulfilled") };

const Process = {
    sequence: async function (tasks) {
        const results = [];
        for (let task of tasks) {
            try {
                results.push(await task.run());
            } catch(err) {
                throw results.concat(err);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
};

console.log('Wait for the results to come in...');
Process.sequence([p1, p2, p3]).then(function(result){
    console.log('Fulfilled: ', result);
}).catch(function(reason){
    console.log('Rejected: ', reason);
});
```

Comment: Your code is extremely easy to read and to understand. Thank you!